# reverse tunnel with ssh: channel 0: connection failed: Connection refused

Tags: portforwarding, tunnel, sshd

I am trying to set up a reverse ssh tunnel between a local machine behind a router and a machine on the Internet, so that the Internet machine can tunnel back and mount a disk on the local machine.

On the local machine, I type

```
/usr/bin/ssh -N -f -R *:2222:127.0.0.1:2222 root@ip_of_remote_machine
```

This causes the remote machine to listen on port 2222. But when I try to mount the sshfs disk on the remote machine, I get "connection refused" on the local machine. Interestingly, port 2222 doesn't show up on the local machine as being bound. However, I'm definitely talking to ssh on the local machine since it complains

`debug1: channel 0: connection failed: Connection refused`

I have GatewayPort set to Yes on both machines. I also have AllowTcpForwarding yes on both machines as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, the line needs to be

`/usr/bin/ssh -N -f -R *:2222:127.0.0.1:22 root@ip_of_remote_machine`

Where port 22 represents the ssh server of the local machine.

Second, since I am using sshfs, the following line needs to be in its sshd_config

`Subsystem sftp /usr/lib64/misc/sftp-server`